# how can I make template of blogger from PSD files !

Tags: xml, blogger

I'd like to change my template on my blog;
I design a template using the gaint PhotoShop
but; how can I make template of blogger from PSD files !

Comment: in the future, please don't multi-post

Answer (score 2):

You may want to get stated with this resource i found about PSD and Blogger platform. [Free Blogger Template PSD](http://www.chethstudios.net/2009/07/quality-free-blogger-templates-psd.html)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to be a little more specific, champ.  Are you asking how to markup and style a new HTML template from a PSD file?

What blogging engine are you using? Wordpress etc..?